# A REALLY huge 3D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector, 3d

The point is: I'm writing a kind of dumb program that takes a BMP image of a handdrawn sound wave and converts it to actual sound. It works fine, but I'm searching for a good way to load the whole image to memory. I currently used std::vector to load a 500 MB image just to see in Task Manager that the process has allocated so much of my 8GB RAM that it needed additional paging (stopped at around 6 GB). I guess it's some kind of overhead...

And here's my question: is there a more memory-efficient way to allocate huge 3D arrays? And is there any speed-efficient way to read huge files byte by byte? (I'm writing this while waiting for it to load, it's 85% after ~50 minutes)

*EDIT*
The OS is 64-bit Windows. And it's even more than 6GB, the RAM was just too small for it, so Windows started putting the array in the paging file (I made a little percentage indicator and allocating was around around 80% at that moment)..

and here's the code I'm using for allocation

```
vector <vector<vector<char> > > raster_data; //declaration
raster_data.resize(width);
for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
    raster_data[i].resize(height);

    for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
    {
        raster_data[i][j].resize(3); //(24bpp=3Bpp)
    }
}
```

so I'm writing data not via push_back(), but by accessing vector like a normal array:

```
raster_data[i][j][k] // in a 3d for loop
```

Comment: That's the kind of task where it would be appropriate to just read an unsigned char array and use OS APIs (e.g. ReadFile on Win32)

Comment: How does 500mb become 6gbs?

Comment: did you use constructor with # of items specified or did you call vector.reserve()? 6Gb might be from massive reallocation on filling via push_back

Comment: You might want to try a memory mapped file. Implementation is different on Windows / Linux  and you did not specify which OS.

Comment: You may reserve a huge size first (std::vector::reserve) and shrink that after computation (std::vector::shrink_to_fit). You may induce a bad memory fragmentation which can be resolved after the last computation, only)

Comment: For large file processing I would recommend against utilizing std::containers and instead work with the raw bytes.... I'm not sure how 500mb became 6 gigs. Seams like an awful lot of overhead even if you are attempting to load this int std::vector<unsigned char>...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you call a 3D array is more a 2D array containing RGB elements, and 500Mb is really not 'REALLY huge' those days.

You approach of using `std::vector` to store only 3 bytes (`char`) should be avoided as:

- the `std::vector` ifself consumes much more that 3 bytes (you may know how much by inspecting the result of `sizeof(std::vector<char>)`.
- the memory you allocate is fragmented

Traditionnally, for your use case, which is loading a 2D bitmap, the memory is allocated in a single block, and then, values accessed using a computed index.

Overly simplified, this would be something like :

```
struct rgb {            // you should check that sizeof(rgb) == 3*sizeof(char), just to be sure
  char channels[3];
};
std::vector<rgb> raster_data;
raster_data.resize(width*height);
// channel access :
raster_data[j*width+i][k] = ...;
```

You could read the entire file contents efficiently in a buffer like this, but you would need to consider the alignment for each rows, and off the top of my head, I can't really say which it is (I believe each row is aligned on a 4 bytes boundary).

For you to learn more about handling BMP bitmap data in C/C++, I strongly suggest you get a look at Handmade Hero, that covers the topic from the beginning, I believe in this episode : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofMJUSchXwo

Comment: To be precise: the vector needs to store two pointer sized values in addition to the three bytes payload. From the given figures I also deduce that the `std::vector<>` implementation that's used does not optimize for small allocations, so the OP also has to pay for dynamic allocation, which is another two pointer sized values. On a 64 bit machine, that's `4*sizeof(size_t) + 3 + alignment = 35 + alignment` bytes to store three bytes which corresponds well with the factor 12 given in the OP.